# Azure Policy CreationDate Tag

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm trying to create an Azure Policy which creates a tag called "CreatedDate" to all the resources for a given scope with the proper Date and Time.

If we are updating the resource (using IaC/PowerShell/CLI/Portal) the value of the CreatedDate shouldn't be modified

Below is the definition of the Azure Policy

```
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "tags['CreatedDate']",
            "exists": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "append",
        "details": [
          {
            "field": "tags['CreatedDate']",
            "value": "[concat(substring(utcNow(),5,2),'/', substring(utcNow(),8,2),'/',substring(utcNow(),0,4),'-',substring(utcNow(),11,8))]"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

The policy is creating the CreatedDate tag for all the resources with proper Date and Time. However the DateTime is getting updated when the resource is updated which is not expected.

Below is how it's behaving now

Resource Created: Aug 15th 2023 10:30 AM

Resource Modified using Bicep/ARM/Terraform and re-deployed on August 20th 2023 11:50

Expectation is to have the Created Date tag to contain Aug 15th 2023 10:30 AM. However, the value of the Creted Date tag is getting updated to August 20th 2023 11:50

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> The policy is creating the CreatedDate tag for all the resources with proper Date and Time. However the DateTime is getting updated when the resource is updated which is not expected.

The effect type **append** is appending the **CreatedDate** tag whenever it doesn't exist. it means every time a resource is **updated or modified**, the policy will append a new timestamp to the **CreatedDate** tag.

You can change **effect** set to **modify** and a single modification operation is specified. This will set the **CreatedDate tag** only if it doesn't already exist, and once set, it will remain unchanged even if the resource is updated in the future.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags['CreatedDate']",
          "exists": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "modify",
      "details": {
        "operations": [
          {
            "operation": "add",
            "field": "tags['CreatedDate']",
            "value": "[concat(substring(utcNow(), 5, 2), '/', substring(utcNow(), 8, 2), '/', substring(utcNow(), 0, 4), '-', substring(utcNow(), 11, 8))]"
          }
        ],
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/36243c78-bf99-498c-9df9-86d9f8d28608"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

The **CreatedDate** tag has been successfully added to the resource once the policy is assigned to a specific scope.

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @venkat, i tried the 'modify' option too. But, it doesn't work. In both the above screenshots, you showed the CreatedDate tags. However, did you try modifying the resource using some kind of IaC? If you do, then the CreatedDate wouldn't remain same. It would change to the latest deployment date.

Comment: My req is not to change the value of the CreatedDate tag even after multiple depoyments to the resource. Hope it makes sense?

Comment: added an example in the original question

Comment: If you create a resource on August 15th, 2023, at 10:30 AM, and then run the same code on August 20th, 2023, at 11:50 AM, Terraform will destroy the existing resource if you make any changes to the code. For example, if you initially create a Virtual Network (VNet) with the address range 10.0.0.0/16 and later try to modify it to 20.0.0.0/24, Terraform will destroy the existing VNet and create a new one with the new address range. without tags, so policy is applying Date tag again with same date August 20th, 2023.

Comment: I created subnets within an existing VNet using this [Terraform code](https://i.imgur.com/3QrZPC4.png). While this code doesn't change the Tag value, if I attempt to modify the VNet using Terraform code, it [destroys the existing VNet and creates a new VNet without the tag](https://i.imgur.com/3NNrOhy.png). As a result, the policy continues to apply the data tag with current data to the same VNet.

Comment: In real-world you won't be deleting and re-creating resources.

Comment: If possible, kindly add a snapshot of the output of the Terraform code, showing how you are modifying the existing resources. While modifying the resource, what is it showing? Is it modifying or destroying and creating?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254921/discussion-between-venkat-v-and-prawin).